# How can I remove content from Github and get my repo in sync with my local code?

Tags: git, command-line, github

I am hosting my blog on Github and have always pushed my new content to the source repo. However, things have changed here and there and I have removed/exchanged some elements of my blog.
Now, I just realized that my all my old stuff is stil on Github. It is like that there is everything I have ever pushed to Github.

My question: What command can I use to get my local code in sync with my Github repo again?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you normally push, I am guessing that in this case there is changed content on the server, so in this case you can:

```
git pull # get the stuff from the server and merge it into your repo.

git push # push the combined stuff back out.
```

However... this is still using unseen magic.  What I actually do these days is the following:

```
git fetch  # First fetch the server changes into your tracking branch
git merge  # Merge those changes into yours
git push   # Push those changes out.
```

Then, in the future, if there are changes on the server, before making local changes you can do:

```
git pull
```

Although here too I prefer:

```
git fetch            # Get the latest
git reset --hard origin/master # set your local to be the same as the tracking branch.
# Make changes locally
# git add .          # Add the changes to git
# git commit -m"msg" # Commit the changes
```

because it avoids accidentally doing an unintended merge to the wrong branch or forgetting about local changes.

All the above assumes you are just working with master.  These days most of my work is done in branches (which incidentally are NOT the same as branches in older Version Control systems such as CVS).

Answer (score 0):

Just `git commit` on your local and do a `git push`

Doc: http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/21/pushing-and-pulling.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get rid of all commits that are in the Github repo, and replace them with the commits that you have locally.
If that is the case, try the following command:

```
git push -f
```

This will push your commits to the server ignoring the history that was already there.

BEWARE: You will lose all the history from your Github repo that is not shared with your local repo, so make sure this is what you want!

Comment: This command comes with *****WARNING*****.  I did this once and wiped out a fellow developers changes.  It's never necessary and I've never used it since.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that was why I added the "BEWARE" note, although it might have been poorly worded.
Still, if your local repository diverged from the remote repository and you are sure you want to discard the remote history, then this is the command to use.

Comment: Sure, good stuff.  I just wanted to emphasize that it wasn't necessarily just about your own history, it could actually mean wiping out other developers current changes in master if they have pushed separately from you, so not just your own history.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to pull data from remote

git pull

If you have locally made commits which are not present on remote then use

git pull --rebase